# Why $M/\mathfrak{a}M \oplus M/\mathfrak{b}M \simeq M/(\mathfrak{a \cap b})M$?

Tags: modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, direct-sum, module-isomorphism

Let $M$ be an $A$-module and let $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ be coprime ideals of A.

I must show that $M/ \mathfrak{a}M \oplus M/ \mathfrak{b}M \simeq M/ (\mathfrak{a \cap b})M$.

My attempt is the following:

Let $x \in M/ \mathfrak{a}M \oplus M/ \mathfrak{b}M$,then $x = [y]+[z]$, where $[y] = y+\mathfrak{a}M $ and $[z]=z + \mathfrak{b}M $, $y,z \in M$.

So, $x = y+z+ \mathfrak{a}M +\mathfrak{b}M $.

$\mathfrak{a}M +\mathfrak{b}M =\{z | z=am_1+bm_2, a \in \mathfrak{a}, b \in \mathfrak{b}   \} $. But then I don't know how to continue.

Is this approach correct? Or is there another way to prove it?
Thanks

Comment: What are $\frak a$ and $\frak b$?

Comment: As always in these types of problems, the key step is to define your maps.  What would be a reasonable map from one of the spaces to the other?

Comment: @AnginaSeng ideals of A. And $M$ is an $A$-module. Sorry for not specifying it.

Comment: Without extra hypotheses, that's not true.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I edited it. The ideals must be coprime

Comment: The statement looks a bit weird when $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr perhaps because the ideals must be coprime? I can't find an isomorphism.  Could it be a projection map?

Comment: Yes, coprime excludes that case.

Comment: As a starting point, this smells like the Chinese Remainder Theorem; maybe a good place to start would be trying to find an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}\equiv \mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$ for distinct primes $p,q$.

Comment: @TomGrubb Thanks! Then in order to prove that the sum is direct I must show that the intersection of the modules is $\{0\}$? Or perhaps I define immediately the map towards the direct sum

Comment: The solutions all assume that $A$ is a commutative ring. However as you did not explicitly state this, it is worth noting that if $A$ is the ring of 2 by 2 matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, then there is a counterexample: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the left ideal of matrices whose second column is $0$ and let $\mathfrak{b}$ be the left ideal of matrices whose first column is $0$. Let $M$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual $A$ action. Then $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=A$, but:
$$M/\mathfrak{a}M\oplus M/\mathfrak{b}M=0,\qquad M/(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})M=M$$

Comment: One of the answers (namely, egreg's answer) shows that $\mathfrak{a}M \cap \mathfrak{b}M=(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b})M$ if $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are coprime. The statement also holds if $M$ is a flat $A$-module. Without assuming coprimality or flatness, the statement fails in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an obvious homomorphism $\varphi\colon M\to M/\mathfrak{a}M\oplus M/\mathfrak{b}M$, namely $\varphi(x)=(x+\mathfrak{a}M,x+\mathfrak{b}M)$.

The kernel is obviously $\mathfrak{a}M\cap\mathfrak{b}M$. You want to prove that $\mathfrak{a}M\cap\mathfrak{b}M=(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})M$, using the known fact that $\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$ when $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=A$.

> We can write $1=a+b$, with $a\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $b\in\mathfrak{b}$. If $x\in\mathfrak{a}M\cap\mathfrak{b}M$, we have $$x=ax+bx\in (\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b})M$$ because $x\in\mathfrak{b}M$ implies $ax\in\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}M$ and $x\in\mathfrak{a}M$ implies $bx\in\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{a}M$. The other inclusion $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}M\subseteq\mathfrak{a}M\cap\mathfrak{b}M$ is obvious. Therefore $\ker\varphi=(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})M$.

Now you want to show that $\varphi$ is also surjective, which is the (abstract version of the) Chinese remainder theorem. If $x,y\in M$, then
$$
(x+\mathfrak{a}M,y+\mathfrak{b}M)=(z+\mathfrak{a}M,z+\mathfrak{b}M)
$$

> where $z=bx+ay$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Consider the short exact sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow A/\mathfrak a\cap\mathfrak b\longrightarrow A/\mathfrak a\times A/\mathfrak b\longrightarrow A/\mathfrak a+\mathfrak b\longrightarrow 0 $$
and tensor by $M$.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}=A$, then $A/(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b})=0$, so all this means is that the other map is an isomorphism.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Bernard thanks! this is a beautiful way to prove it. But can I ask you to explain why tensoring with $M$ gives $M \otimes (A/\mathfrak{a} x A/\mathfrak{b}) = M/\mathfrak{a}M \oplus M/\mathfrak{b}M$?

Comment: Tensor product preserves isomorphisms  and commutes with direct sums. Also, $M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak a\simeq M/\mathfrak aM$.  (unrelated: don't use the letter ‘x’ for the product. MathJax uses the same as LaTeX – in math mode: `\times`).

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's a bit easier to go backwards. Let $[x]\in M/(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})M$. Since $\mathfrak{a}$ contains the ideal $\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b}$, we can restrict $[x]$ to a class $[x_1]\in M/\mathfrak{a}M$, and similarly to a class $[x_2]\in M/\mathfrak{b}M$. We have to show this map is an isomorphism.

Why is it injective? Well, suppose $[x_1] = 0$ and $[x_2] = 0$. That means $x$ was originally in $\mathfrak{a}M$ as well as in $\mathfrak{b}M$, so you are done.

Why is it surjective? Take $([x_1],[x_2])$ on the LHS, and lift them to $x_1,x_2\in M$. Because $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are coprime, there are $a\in \mathfrak{a}$ and $b\in\mathfrak{b}$ for which $a+b = 1$. What happens to the element $x = x_2a+x_1b$?

(EDIT: I should really say that you should define the map from $M$ and then use one of the isomorphism theorems, that makes it much clearer)

Comment: You skipped a minor step: in proving injectivity you assumed that $\mathfrak{a}M\cap\mathfrak{b}M=(\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b})M$.  It follows from $m=(a+b)m$ for the $a,b$ that you defined..